# Login Loop cannot CTR-ALT-F3 to command promt

Tags: command-line, 20.04, login

I am stuck in a login loop.  I see lots of suggestions about getting to a command prompt and either freeing memory, clearing log files, or undoing the last updates and upgrades.  Sadly, when I get to the login page and enter CTR-ALT-F3 I do not see a command prompt.  My mouse and keyboard fail to work anymore but I see see the normal (purple) Ubuntu login page.  How do I get to a command prompt to begin working on my login loop problem?

UPDATE:  Using the advice from @vanadium I have use `esc` to get to a prompt like this `grub>`.  I can use the `tab` to see a list of commands but I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, normally you should be able to reach a TTY, both from the login screen and after you have logged in, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3/4/5...</kbd>. If that also fails, you can always reach a recovery prompt from the Grub menu. You will find detailed instructions with pictures on [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/).

- If your Grub menu is normally not shown during startup, then hold the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to display the Grub menu.
- There, choose the option "Advanced options for Ubuntu".
- Then select an entry ending with "(recovery mode)". That brings you to the recovery menu.
- Select "root Drop to root shell prompt" to enter a prompt with root privileges.